# Branch respective deployment using azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, gitlab

i am using azure-devops for build and release pipelines. For code repository i am using git lab so i configure it by using external generic git repositories . i want branch based deployment. should i have to create separate projects like abc-develop and abc-stage ? If not then how to configure build and release branch respective for same project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should i have to create separate projects like abc-develop and
>   abc-stage ?

For this issue,You don't need to create separate projects.You just need to select the branch you need when running the pipeline.As shown below.
[image]

Comment: I am sorry to give the wrong guide.I have updated my answer.

Comment: I think your previous answer was fine :) As i am using private gitlab repositories so for develop i have separate build and release . so i have to create separate staging build and release pipeline